# How to display json values using poco class in c# and xaml for UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml

p_json:

```
{
"title":"title1",
"value1":"value1",
"objects":{
  "obj1":"obj1",
"obj2":"obj2"
},
"lists":[
{
"time":"11:00 Hrs",
"date":"jan"
},
{
"time":"12:00 hrs",
"date":"feb"
},
{
"time":"10:00",
"date":"mar"
}
]
}
```

POCO :::

```
namespace windows_app.Models
{
    public class EDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value1")]
        public string Value1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("objects")]
        public Object Objects { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lists")]
        public List<List> Lists { get; set; }

    }

    public class Object
    {
        [JsonProperty("obj1")]
        public string Obj1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("obj2")]
        public string Obj2 { get; set; }

    }

    public class List
    {
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }

}
```

.cs::

```
string FilePath ="./Models/pdet.json";

            rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EDetails>(File.ReadAllText(FilePath));

            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
            {
                var json = file.ReadToEnd();
                Dictionary<string, object> result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
                string tLists = result["lists"].ToString();
                List<List> objResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List>>(tourLists);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("objResponse::" + objResponse);
                tListItems.ItemsSource = objResponse;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tItems.ItemsSource " + tItems.ItemsSource);
            }
```

.xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="tItems" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                                <Border  BorderThickness="0 1 0 1" BorderBrush="Gray"  >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5"  >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"  Grid.Column="0"  Margin="10" FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ListView>
```

O/p:

Jan 11:00Hrs

feb  12:00 hrs

mar  10:00 hrs

I want output like this. However, I didn't get output like this. I am getting results like below

windows_app.Models.lists

How to solve this problem. Someone help me to resolve this. I tried, but could not found solutions. Already I spent one day to solve this.

Comment: where is tourList coming from ?

Comment: hi Uma, just curious to know if the solution was able to guide you, let me know if you still need further help

Answer (score 1):

- The issue you are facing is you are trying to directly parse a `List` of type `List` directly, which has 2 properties `Date` and `Time`.
- Leading to unexpected output such as
  `windows_app.Models.lists`
- Created a simple wpf app to recreate the problem please find the snippet below which you can tweak to solve your problem

---

**.MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new DataObject();
        }
    }

    public class EDetails
    {

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value1")]
        public string Value1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("objects")]
        public Object Objects { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lists")]
        public List<List> Lists { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        [JsonProperty("obj1")]
        public string Obj1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("obj2")]
        public string Obj2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class List
    {
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
    public class DataObject
    {

        public IList<string> NewDateTimeList { get; set; }

        public DataObject()
        {

            string FilePath = @"C:\Users\Win10EGL\source\repos\Test\testJson.json";

            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EDetails>(File.ReadAllText(FilePath));

            NewDateTimeList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var element in rootObject.Lists.ToList())
            {

                NewDateTimeList.Add(element.Date + " " + element.Time);
            }
        }
    }
```

**.MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="345,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding NewDateTimeList}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I would name the classes something else than ``Object`` and ``List``.

Comment: Still i am getting the same response:: NewDateTimeListSystem.Collections.Generic.List`Error: BindingExpression path error: 'NewDateTimeList' property not found

Comment: I see your xaml has 'titems' but your code behind is tlistItems,  the issue seems to be with your binding.                                       Besides, as per your error 'NewdatetimeList' property is not found but I dont see such a property in your code

Comment: Take a fresh look at it again, the code that I shared was  tried and tested on my system. Narrow down your issue by using break point and see if the information that your sending back to xaml is right. Now ur one step closer